# Transparent PNG file in a Pure C++/Win32 Application

Tags: winapi

I have a pure C++/Win32 VS2005 desktop application. During my WM_PAINT response, when I paint my window, I'd like to be able to Project a transparent PNG image onto my Window.

any pointer will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you Googled for something like "Windows PNG library" and looked at the results? If so, what problems did you see what what it turned up?

Comment: @JerryCoffin Just FYI, this post is now the top Google result for "paint png winapi", in fact the top four are now all SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[GdiPlus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533798%28VS.85%29.aspx) has been part of Windows since Windows XP at least, and can decode JPEG, PNG and GIF files with ease.

A newer API for dealing with image files is the [Windows Image Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee719902%28VS.85%29.aspx). One of the [samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee719902%28VS.85%29.aspx) covers using WIC to decode an image and GdiPlus to perform the alpha aware painting.

Answer (score 2):

The Windows Imaging Component (WIC) is the primary API for native code that provides the ability to encode and decode various image formats. You can use it to load a PNG image into your application.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee719902

Alternatively you can use GDI+ but that’s pretty old technology and doesn’t work nearly as well. You can also use GDI+ to render the image but I suggest Direct2D.

Direct2D is capable of rendering a WIC bitmap directly on the GPU or in software via a window or bitmap device context.

Here’s an introductory article on Direct2D:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/magazine/dd861344.aspx

And this one describes how to use Direct2D with WIC:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819134.aspx

Comment: I believe WIC requires a minimum of Vista on a target machine. Local constraints here force me to support XP and write code on VS2005. Will WIC still be a good choice given these constraints?

Comment: WIC is available for Windows XP with SP2 and later.